# Converted lead account id null

Tags: leads

I am in process of fixing data issues. 
I realized some of my leads so not have Converted account Id

How is that possible. Please guide

Comment: Do you have any trigger fires on lead conversion?

Comment: Yes but that does not clears accountId. I have more than 9000 reccords in leads table only 39 are missing AccountId,

Answer (score 2):

The account may have been subsequently deleted. This would result in the Converted*Id fields being null. Recovering accounts from the recycle bin would also restore the value in the field. If the account has been purged (permanently deleted), there's nothing you can do except convert the record again.

Comment: I have just checked that. After deleting the related Account the ConvertedAccountId is still there in the database.

Comment: @LanceShi I think there's a delay before the fields clear themselves out, but I don't know how long it'd be. I know I recall seeing this behavior before, but I suspect it's not until the periodic hard data purge that occurs every day or so for records that have been permanently erased.

Comment: Nice. Learnt something new from you again!

Comment: @LanceShi Get back to me in 24 hours and see if I'm still right. I'm running an experiment in my developer account right now...

Comment: I am doing the same thing. I will check it tomorrow, too.

Answer (score 1):

You can manually change the status of lead into Closed - converted without actually converting it.

Comment: I checked status with SOQL its 'Qualified' and isConverted is true.